# Почему в мануале php отсутствует ключевик object?

Tags: php, объекты

Вопрос к познавшим php. Почему в мануале php [Список ключевых слов](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.keywords.php) отсутствует ключевик *object*? Собственно не почему, а возможные причины его отсутствия, есть ли объективные причины его невостребованности!

Пара строк кода для примера

```
$row = array('user' => (object) array('name' => 'John', 'age' => '27'));

echo $row['user']->name, $row['user']->age;

// или берем из бд

if($row = mysql_fetch_array($db))
{
    $row = (object) $row;

    echo $row->name; //и т.д.
}
```

Спасибо за просветление мозга.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting to object

If an object is converted to an object, it is not modified. If a value of any other type is converted to an object, a new instance of the stdClass built-in class is created. If the value was NULL, the new instance will be empty. Arrays convert to an object with properties named by keys, and corresponding values. For any other value, a member variable named scalar will contain the value.

```
<?php
$obj = (object) 'ciao';
echo $obj->scalar;  // outputs 'ciao'
?>
```